# Netty 4 binary decoder issue

Tags: java, netty

I am trying to move from Mina to Netty 4 and try to implement 101 decoder of binary frames organized with the header containing frame length. Being a complete novice to Netty I took an example found on the net and tried to execute it. I must be doing a novice error as the code does not work according to my expectations. Here is the code:

```
public class NettyNioServer {

    public void server(int port) throws Exception {
       ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        try {       
            b.group(new NioEventLoopGroup(), new NioEventLoopGroup())
            .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
            .localAddress(new InetSocketAddress(port))
            .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
            .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {

                 @Override
                 public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                   ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                   p.addLast("frameDecoder", new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(1048576, 0, 2, 0, 2));
                   p.addLast("bytesDecoder", new ByteArrayDecoder());
                   p.addLast(new NioHandler());

                   }
        }); 
            ChannelFuture f = b.bind().sync();
            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            b.group()
             .shutdownGracefully().sync();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println(
                    "Usage: " + NettyNioServer.class.getSimpleName() +
                    " <port>");
            return;
        }
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println("start on port: "+port);
        new NettyNioServer().server(port);
    }
}
```

The handler code is as follows:

```
public class NioHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {



@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
     byte[] bytes = (byte[]) msg;
     System.out.println(bytes.length+" bytes received");
}



@Override
public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
     ByteBuf buf1 =Unpooled.copiedBuffer("Well received bye! \r\n", Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
     ctx.writeAndFlush(buf1.duplicate()).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
     System.out.println("Answer send");
}



@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Exception caught: "+ cause.getMessage());

}



}
```

And here is what I receive:

```
start on port: 7777
janv. 02, 2016 8:15:47 PM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler channelRegistered
INFOS: [id: 0x01f2254e] REGISTERED
janv. 02, 2016 8:15:47 PM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler bind
INFOS: [id: 0x01f2254e] BIND(0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:7777)
janv. 02, 2016 8:15:47 PM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler channelActive
INFOS: [id: 0x01f2254e, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:7777] ACTIVE
janv. 02, 2016 8:17:14 PM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler logMessage
INFOS: [id: 0x01f2254e, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:7777] RECEIVED: [id: 0x47c24c03, /127.0.0.1:50737 => /127.0.0.1:7777]
Answer send
```

Why is my channelRead never executed?

Answer (score 1):

Your handler implementation seems to be correct.

So, no data is read on this handler. It is because one other handler before on pipeline catches data (probably to handle it) but it doesn't finish and doesn't push data for other handlers on pipeline.

Make sure to write data correctly on input according to `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` specification: http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.html

Or maybe remove this decoder if you don't really need it.

You can also add a LoggingHandler top of your pipeline to see what is received by adding:

```
p.addFirst("logHandler", new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO));
```

FYI, your NioHandler can also extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler instead of ChannelInboundHandler which is more generic

Comment: You are perfectly right Prim. My server was OK but my client was badly constructed and the header was erroneous. So the LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder never got enough of data and blocked till the closure of the connection , which caused channelReadComplete to execute. Thanks for your hint. My problem is now solved

Comment: @JacekSzymanski Consider marking the answer as accepted if it seems ok for you to help readers with similar problem